# Stubbing with Wiremock - WithBodyFile Location other than _files

Tags: java, stubbing, wiremock

Wiremock Documentation states that the location of the file specified in *withBodyFile* should be in **src/test/resources/__files**. I would like to have file in **src/test/resources/Testing_ABC/Testcase2/myfile.xml.**

Is there any way I can achieve this ? I tried following, but it does not seem to work !

```
stubFor(get(urlPathEqualTo("/abc")).willReturn
                (aResponse().withHeader("Content-Type",
                        "text/xml; charset=utf-8").withHeader
                        ("Content-Encoding",
                                "gzip")
                        .withBodyFile
                                ("src/test/resources/Testing_ABC/Testcase2/myfile.xml)));
```

However, when I put my file in src/test/resources/__files/myfile.xml and change the path accordingly, it works fine.

I am just wondering if I can make wiremock look in some other directory in resources other than __files just in order to have nice resource structure in project.

Comment: According to http://wiremock.org/docs/configuration/ you should be able to change the resources location. Keep in mind this changes the location of all files within the `resources` directory.

Comment: What is the reason you want to have a different location?

Comment: @A.Kootstra - Why do you ask?

Comment: Because that reason may be solved in another manner, which is something that should be looked at given that this is hard-coded in the software.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this Kotlin Config class to customize the Root Directory.
It still requires response file to be in the __files directory.

```
@Configuration
class Config: WireMockConfigurationCustomizer {
    override fun customize(config: WireMockConfiguration?) {
        config!!.withRootDirectory("customer-client/src/test/resources")
    }
}

@AutoConfigureWireMock
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java & Spock but still using `__files` folder

```
@TestConfiguration
public class WireMockConfig {

    @Bean
    public WireMockConfigurationCustomizer wireMockConfigurationCustomizer() {
        return config -> {
            config.withRootDirectory("src/integration-test/resources");
        };
    }
}
```

Then where ever you have `ApplicationContext` initializer :

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = [Application.class, WireMockConfig.class], webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration()
abstract class WireMockIntegrationSpec extends Specification {
}
```

Then in your test :

```
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 9089)
@Unroll
class ApplicationSpec extends WireMockIntegrationSpec {

    def "Some test" () {
    }
}
```

Your resources will be served from `src/integration-test/resources/__files`.
**Make sure this directory structure exists**

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be changed. You always need a "__files" dir. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61593477/changing-wiremock-files-directory#comment-124852848) and the comment by @luckyluke.

But the part before that can be changed.

It can be done like:

```java
WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(
    wireMockConfiguration.options()
        .usingFilesUnderDirectory("src/test/resources/something")
);
```

Or, without changing the `src/test/resources` part, only appending more levels under it:

```java
wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(8090, new ClasspathFileSource("integration/responses"), false);
```

The logic used by Wiremock is not very straightforward, but I will put my findings here:

- Wiremock will get the default root dir, which is `src/test/resources`(or other path specified in the 1st approach); or, if you use 2nd approach above, Wiremock will append that part after `src/test/resources`.
- Wiremock will then append "__files" part, which cannot be changed.
- It reads the value in "withBodyFile(value)", and join all to form a `Path`.

So, for example, if I want to read `job-resource.json` under `src/test/resources/integration/responses`, I need to create a `__files` under this dir, put the json into it, launch the wiremock server in the 2nd approach, and then:

```
wiremock.stubFor(
    get(urlPathMatching("xxx"))
            .withId(stubId)
            .willReturn(
                    aResponse()
                            .withStatus(200)
                            .withBodyFile("job-resource.json") // note here it's just filename, not "__files/job-resource.json"
            );
);
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be something you need to configure when creating the rule. Try

```
@Rule
public final WireMockRule rule = new WireMockRule(WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig()
  .withRootDirectory("src/test/resources/Testing_ABC"));
```

and then you probably can use `.withBodyFile("Testcase2/myfile.xml)` in test.

Comment: Thanks for your response Henri. I tried what u suggested. But it looks like wiremock searches the files in src/test/resources/Testing_ABC/__files/Testcase2/myfile.xml. So it expects __files directory somehow, which I would like to avoid.