# Changing WireMock __files directory

Tags: java, unit-testing, wiremock, stubbing

From the [docs](http://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/):

> To read the body content from a file, place the file under the __files
>   directory. By default this is expected to be under src/test/resources
>   when running from the JUnit rule. When running standalone it will be
>   under the current directory in which the server was started. To make
>   your stub use the file, simply call bodyFile() on the response builder
>   with the file’s path relative to __files:

Is it possible to change it? Why would WireMock insist on this specific directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WireMock insists on that specific directory because it has to have some specific directory.

If you want to change it, you can do so. [Check out the `File Locations` section under the configuration documentation.](http://wiremock.org/docs/configuration/)

Comment: It's possible to change the root folder, but the `__files` child folder is not changeable. It's declared [here](https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/core/WireMockApp.java#L169) and transferred to the StubResponseRenderer. The filesource is then used everywhere.

Comment: Thanks @luckyluke for investigating this for all of us. Please consider make it an answer and I will upvote. For example, in this same question, and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48203837/stubbing-with-wiremock-withbodyfile-location-other-than-files)